# Is there a way to make the sticky notes more like a permanent addition to the desktop?

Tags: sticky-notes, timeline

when I first found StickNotes I was thrilled.  I was using it to keep notes on some programming changes in PHP database modules.  Of course, as all good codehackers reading the directions is what you do After the problems occur.  So I lost all my notes.

But it sure would be nice to leave notes like a chalkboard on the background of the screen you are working on.  Those bits of paper I normally use always end up in the twilight zone and by 3 am I can't remember enough to get my train of though back to where I was.

It would be so nice to scrawl in the margins of my desktop background, and get keep my scrawling separated to save into a file for future review.

A feature where erasing one Notepad would really store "wipe it into" a file like the recycle bin, where it coule be uncrumpled later And automatic Timed saves like snapshots of all the notepads could even be gathered for easy recovery of a train of thought.

Anyone know of anything like that?

Comment: Instead of sticky notes why not use a program like Microsoft OneNote or EverNote?  They will do the same thing and allow you to capture screen shots of whatever you want.  Record audio for later and more.  It may help you get your train of thought back.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an article written July 16th 2009 entitled **"Get the Vista Sticky Notes Sidebar Gadget for Windows 7"**. It explains how it is very similar to the Notes Gadget in Vista the steps you need to take to install it in Windows 7. It will install in your desktop gadgets folder in Windows 7. It may be to your liking.

http://www.ithinkdiff.com/get-the-vista-notes-sidebar-gadget-for-windows-7/

Comment: Its been proven that these Gadgets are not secure.  So much so that Microsoft basically has suggested not using them.  The better solution is to use OneNote or EverNote for this type of functionality.

Comment: @Ramhound: Ah ok fine, thanks for notifying. When you mean secure...you mean in terms of malware security or ....?

Comment: The gadget support was removed in Windows 8. There is a known issue that makes the security of these gadgets questionable at best. Clearly the default gadgets are secure but others might not be.  I do believe there is a notice on the website you normally would download them at indicating Microsoft's current stance.  Some people argue its a politcal move except the security vulerability was discovered by a third-party and only after that vulerability was made public did Microsoft drop support for the gadgets ( were talking 12-14 months ago ) from Windows 8.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thx for explaining....Good to know